# How to calculate the hourly Max over a month, promql

Tags: promql, sql-server-mars

I have the following query, intended to calculate for each hour the max value, over a month.
The final result should be- for each parentnode, the hourly max over the last month

I have this for now:

```
max_over_time((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{site="fra",parentnode="compute_node"} - node_memory_MemFree_bytes{site="fra",parentnode="compute_node"} - node_memory_Cached_bytes{site="fra",parentnode="compute_node"} - node_memory_Buffers_bytes{site="fra",parentnode="compute_node"} - node_memory_Slab_bytes{site="fra",parentnode="compute_node"})[1h])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to use subqueries ([blog post](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/)) or recording rules ([example](https://www.robustperception.io/composing-range-vector-functions-in-promql)) to first calculate the avg per hour for a month and then max over time for a month.

With subqueries your query would look like this:

```
max_over_time(avg_over_time(node_memory[1h])[30d:5m])
```

You can play around with the resolution. But I recommend recording rules once you have worked out your panels